# ChamaleonPi emulators ignore uinput keypresses

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, chameleonpi

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi Gameboy. I've installed [chameleonpi](http://chameleon.enging.com/) on the Raspberry Pi and made a custom button board that is connected to the GPIO Pins. I've also written a Python script which runs in the background, listens on the GPIO and produces keypresses via the [python-uinput](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/) module.

I can control the Chameleon Pi menus with the GPIO button pad, but not the emulators.
The emulators ignore uinput keypresses. Any ideas?